# Как нарисовать линию поверх QPixmap PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, рисование, qpixmap, paintevent

Пишу *MP3-Player*. Только начал писать и сразу же столкнулся с проблемой, о решении которой толком ничего не нашел в гугле.

Как нарисовать линию поверх `QPixmap`?

**UPD**: Причем кнопки, надписи и другие виджеты спокойно расставляются поверх `QPixmap`.

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *
import sys

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.resize(800,500)
        self.setFixedSize(self.size())
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon("images/mp3-player.ico"))
        self.setWindowTitle("MP3-Player")
        
        self.background_image_pixmap = QPixmap("images/background.jpg")
        self.background_image = QLabel(self)
        
        self.background_image.setGeometry(0, 0, 800, 500)
        self.background_image.setPixmap(self.background_image_pixmap)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self.background_image)
        painter.setPen(Qt.black)
        painter.drawLine(0,0,100,50)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.resize(512, 512)
#        self.setFixedSize(self.size())
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon("images/mp3-player.ico"))
        self.setWindowTitle("MP3-Player")
        
        self.image = QPixmap("lena.jpg")                            # +++
        w = self.image.size().width()
        h = self.image.size().height()
        
        self.background_image = QLabel("<h2 style='color: blue'>lena.jpg</h2>", self)
        self.background_image.move(w-240, h-100)
        
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)            
        painter.drawPixmap(QPoint(), self.image)                    # +++
        painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.red, 5))
        painter.drawLine(10, 10, 500, 500)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @Bitchdragon пожалуйста.